# Show that the vector $u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent if and only if $u_1v_2-v_1u_2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vectors, solution-verification

$$u=
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$v=
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is what I have done:

$$u_1/u_2=v_1/v_2 <=> u_1/u_2 = t*v_1/t*v_2$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2\\
\end{bmatrix}*x+ \begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}*y=s*
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$<=>$$

$$t*
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}*x+ \begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}*y=s*
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Because $t$ and $x$ arejust scalars we can write the equation like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}*x+ \begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}*y=s*
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Factor $v$ vector and get:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}*(x+y) =s*
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So as as long as we chose scalars $x, y$ and $t$ such that the equation $x+y=s$ is valid then that means that $v, u$ are linearly dependent.

My question is if that is a correct explanation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u=
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
v=
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$

are linearly independent if and only if the only $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}$ such as $xu+yv=0$ are $(x,y)=(0,0)$

$xu+yv=\begin{bmatrix} u_1 v_1\\
u_2 v_2\\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\
y\\\end{bmatrix}=0$

Which happens only for a matrix with a non-zero determinant.

Thus, on the contrary, $u$ and $v$ are dependent if and only if the matrix have a zero determinant, that is

$u_1v_2-u_2v_1=0$

Comment: Thank you! I suspected it had something to do with determinants

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, two nonzero vectors, $u$ and $v$, are linearly dependent iff there exists some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$u=\lambda v \iff u_1 = \lambda v_1\quad\text{and}\quad u_2=\lambda v_2.$$
If $u_2 = \lambda v_2 \neq 0$ (or if $u_1=\lambda v_1 \neq 0$ you can take the other fractions), then the above conditions hold iff
$$
\frac{u_1}{u_2} = \frac{\lambda v_1}{\lambda v_2} = \frac{v_1}{v_2}\iff u_1v_2-v_1u_2=0.
$$